# If/else nested loop syntax errors; error: object not found that is defined within function? Windows 8.1, RStudio 0.99.467, R3.2.1

Tags: r, function, compiler-errors

I began programming in R roughly 2.5 weeks ago. It is the first language I have ever tried to learn. My current challenge is to write a function that does as follows:

"Write a function that takes a directory of data files (332 csvs containing 4 columns -- date, level of sulfate (lots of NA values), level of nitrate (lots of NA values), and pollutant monitor id number that is also the same as the csv file name) and a threshold for complete cases and calculates the correlation between sulfate and nitrate for monitor locations where the number of completely observed cases (on all variables) is greater than the threshold. The function should return a vector of correlations for the monitors that meet the threshold requirement. If no monitors meet the threshold requirement, then the function should return a numeric vector of length 0."

A prototype of this function follows:

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
        ## 'directory' is a character vector of length 1 indicating
        ## the location of the CSV files

        ## 'threshold' is a numeric vector of length 1 indicating the
        ## number of completely observed observations (on all
        ## variables) required to compute the correlation between
        ## nitrate and sulfate; the default is 0

        ## Return a numeric vector of correlations
        ## NOTE: Do not round the result!
}
```

Here is my function to date (I incorporated a function developed earlier that printed out a data frame containing two columns -- id and nobs.)

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
  files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
  nobs <- c()
  cns <- c()
  for (i in id) {
    dat <- read.csv(files_list[i]) #creates data frame "dat" with data from all 332 files in it
    nobs <- c(nobs, sum(complete.cases(dat))) #creates column "nobs" populated with number of complete cases for all variables, per id number
    cns <- c(cns, cor(dat$sulfate, dat$nitrate, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")) #creates column "cns" populated with Pearson correlation between nitrate and sulfate, with all NAs removed
  }
  data.frame(cns, nobs, id) #creates dataframe "data.frame" populated with variables cns, nobs, and id
}
corr <- function(directory, threshold=0){
  nobsdf <- complete(directory, id=1:332)
for (i in threshold) {
  threshold <- nobsdf$nobs
  if threshold >= nobsdf$nobs {
    nobsdf$cns #if threshold value is equal to or bigger than nobs value, print cns value
  } else { #else print 0
    0
}
}
```

When I run the function, it gives this output:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"        threshold <- nobsdf$nobs
        if threshold"
>             nobsdf$cns #if threshold value is equal to or bigger than nobs value, print cns value
Error: object 'nobsdf' not found
>         } else { #else print 0
Error: unexpected '}' in "        }"
>             0
[1] 0
>         }
Error: unexpected '}' in "        }"
>     }
Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
>
```

What I want it to give, however, is this output:

```
source("corr.R")
source("complete.R")
cr <- corr("specdata", 150)
head(cr)

## [1] -0.01896 -0.14051 -0.04390 -0.06816 -0.12351 -0.07589
summary(cr)
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
## -0.2110 -0.0500  0.0946  0.1250  0.2680  0.7630
cr <- corr("specdata", 400)
head(cr)
## [1] -0.01896 -0.04390 -0.06816 -0.07589  0.76313 -0.15783
summary(cr)
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
## -0.1760 -0.0311  0.1000  0.1400  0.2680  0.7630
cr <- corr("specdata", 5000)
summary(cr)
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
## 
length(cr)
## [1] 0
cr <- corr("specdata")
summary(cr)
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
## -1.0000 -0.0528  0.1070  0.1370  0.2780  1.0000
length(cr)
## [1] 323
```

**My questions:**

1. Why is nobsdf undefined when I defined it earlier in the function? I know from testing the function (with one more closed bracket) up to "nobsdf <- complete(directory, id=1:332)" that nobdsf is defined up to that point. (I know this because if I tell the function to print output, it does as expected (i.e. prints a data frame containing cns, nobs and id).
2. Why am I getting so many errors about the brackets? How can I fix the syntax to avoid this?
3. Why does the function print a 0 in the middle of my output? How can I avoid this? I only want my function to print 0 if threshold is bigger than nobs.

**Any and all help, suggestions, and directions to additional learning lessons is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.**

Comment: `if threshold >= nobsdf$nobs` needs braces `()` i.e. `if( threshold >= nobsdf$nobs)`  You may find duplicates for this question by googling.

Comment: Thank you, akrun. Your solution with adding the () worked. I can now continue troubleshooting much more effectively (function still does not do what I need, though now it does not throw errors). I am trying to do my own work on this problem, because it is associated with a class... and I like the challenge. I figure that posting this should be okay, since I am mid-stream with it and this function draft does not give away the answer (and as of yet does not meet the solution).